# How to add attachment to new email in Lotus Notes from command line

Tags: windows, lotus-notes

I am trying to create a new email from command line and automatically add an attachment. The following is the closest I have gotten, it works apart from adding the attachment. I have also tried using &attach=... and &attachment=...

start mailto:emailadress?subject=My email&body=some text&attachments="c:/AUTOEXEC.BAT"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It works using the following commmand:

`C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes>notes mailto:email@address.com?attach=c:\autoexec.bat`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, just what i needed!

If you still want **subject** and **body** you'd have to escape the "&" (with ^). Else it is interpreted as a new command.
e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes>notes mailto:email@address.com?subject=My email^&body=some text^&attach=c:\autoexec.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

This lasted until version 11. In version 11, the Notes client does not want to attach files.
From the batch file I need to prepare an email to be sent. All message fields are already pre-filled in the command line.

```
notes.exe mailto:uname@abc.com?subject=Test?body=Test^&attach=test.txt
```

This command worked in versions 9 and 10. In version 11, Notes does not attach the file.
The graphical interface will be opened, the human sender checks visually and finally presses the send button.