# How to send email from alternative address from Lotus Notes from command line?

Tags: command-line, lotus-notes, email-client

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/344047/how-to-add-attachment-to-new-email-in-lotus-notes-from-command-line/344057#344057) answer shows how to send an email from the default address of Lotus Notes. We, however, also have something like a common email address to our department, with a common inbox. My question is how I can send from this email address. I have already tried the following two commands:

```
notes mailto:email@address.com?sender=common@inbox.dk
notes mailto:email@address.com?from=common@inbox.dk
```

EDIT: There seems to be [scripting functionality](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/80a578b71732144085256d6b00478e67?OpenDocument) (VBS), which maybe could be used.

Comment: Do you still need help with this, I assume from your edit that you figured it out.

Comment: @Zach I never figured it out, but there is only a 5% chance that I will apply any solution if someone provided one now. Thank you for asking, though.

Comment: I won't go looking for a solution then, but will update if I happen across anything that may help.